# изменить язык интерфейса windows 10

Tags: windows-10

не получается поменять язык интерфейса oc, может кто то знает как можно решить этот вопрос без переустановки windows, как видно на скриншотах нет кнопок установить язык по умолчанию или как язык интерфейса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть сменить регион. Но это не точно)

Comment: @ЭдикБилый не помогает, это только для местной рекламой и поиска

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема решена, обновлением windows до pro версии

Comment: А проблема действительно была? На скринах установлен язык интерфейса - русский, и показывается на русском. Всё  вроде правильно.

Comment: @0xdb на английский менял интерфейс

Comment: Смущает строчка "Разрешено использовать только один языковый пакет". Кем разрешено? У меня, например, стоит Home, такой строчки нет, и могу переключать на любой язык без перехода на Pro.

Comment: @0xdb в интернете пишут что home версия только один язык поддерживает

Comment: Может быть. У меня пока  Home 1803, и если я наконец соглашусь перейти на 1903, то может и у меня заберут возможность выбора.

Comment: @0xdb у меня home 1809 стояла